# count characters in a textview

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nstimer, character

i want to count the characters in a textview which are typed in by the user. I gave it some thoughts and my ideas were that I have to create a NSTimer with a selector which checks the length.
So I've got:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad { [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(checkText) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];  }

-(void)checkText {

int characters;

label.text.length = self.characters;

characterLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", characters]; }
```

This doesn't work because "Request for member "characters" in something not a structure or union"

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for NSTimer. Setup yourself as textview's delegate and implement:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSUInteger length;
    length = [textView.text length];

    characterLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", length]
}
```

Comment: `characterLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", length];`*

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if you are trying to use `self.characters` to get `int characters` variable's value - it won't work. `self.characters` code means you have a property setup `@property characters` and it will call this property's getter. To use local variable just use its name.

I think you have mixed-up label objects in your `-checkText:` method.
Here's a generic example of how to get `UITextView`'s number of characters:

```
int characters = [myTextView.text length];
```

Comment: actually this is no answer to my question

Comment: I see. I've added some details, hope you'll find them helpful.

Comment: "In Objective-C any method name includes : symbol" - that is no true

Comment: Bartosz is right; the colon would be there only if that selector takes an argument. checkText doesn't take an argument, so no colon in the selector.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, Bartosz and Tommy. I'll remove it from my answer.